# Subtraction of two dates in django query

Tags: django, model, date, subtraction

```
class Case( models.Model ):
created          = models.DateTimeField()    
modified          = models.DateTimeField()

STATUS = (
    ('Active', 'Active'),
    ('Hold', 'Hold'),
    ('Expired', 'Expired'),
    ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
)
status     = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=STATUS)
```

Now i want to extract records, having status expired less than 2 months ago, simply expired more than 2 months ago shouldn't be counted.

i have read  [`__here subtraction of dates`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django/en/latest/topics/db/queries.html#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) but it doesn't work in my case.

```
 expired_cases = Case.objects.filter( status = 'Expired', modified__lt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=60) ).count()
```

this kind of query may work but i didn't want to hard code the days in this.

Please help me in this issue. 
thanx in advance :)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the question is.  The `Case.objects.filter(...` call you have there, did you try it?  Did it work?  ...You certainly don't have to hard code the number of days... you can put it in the Django settings file, pass it as a parameter to a view, etc.

Comment: above query works but i didn't want to hard code the 60 days for two month, because i didn't know the previous two months are of 30 days, may be one is 30 and other 28, or 31. So i want such query which independent of hard coding the days.

Comment: Alright, I gave an answer to your question but I realized a fixed number of days, say 60, is still better than counting the days of the previous months. If I am in the middle, say March 8 (today), when exactly is two months ago? You don't count the days in Feb and Jan for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's calendar lib to return a list of days. Note that it doesn't handle leap years so you need to implement a solution for that.

```
>>> days = calendar.mdays
[0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Get the days of the current month this way, then calculate the timedelta you need. You'll need to strip the first element from the list to make it work.

```
>>> days = days[1:]
>>> month = datetime.date.today().month-1 #-1 due to 0-based indexing in list
>>> delta = days[month-1] + days[month-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the python-dateutil module. Create a **Python** datetimeobject out of the modified time ans subtract. It should work.

Comment: `<field>__lt` in Django means to filter on values in the field that are less than the argument.  `modified__lt` should not be a problem.

Comment: modified__lt means modified less than assignment value its not a problem.

Comment: Oh I didn't knew this :-/ Sorry for the noise